# Powershell Script to get items only in a particular view of SharePoint List/library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sharepoint-library

Is there a way to get the items that are present in a particular view of a sharepoint library? Actually my library has multiple levels of folders like this:

```
Level1 Document set
Level2 Folders and some Items
Level3 Folders and some items ...so on
```

what I am trying to do is I will select the "Show all Items without folders" option in view and try to access all the items using powershell, since that will be easier. How can I do it? 
Here is my script as requested:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://MySite"
$library = $web.Lists["Test"]
$view = $library.Views["All Documents"]
foreach($item in $list.GetItems($view))
{
 write-host $item["Name"]
}
```

Actual content of All documents view 
[image: Actual content of All documents view :]

Content After Filter:
[image: Content After Filter :]

The ouput is : 
A
B 
C
while it should be only A right?

Comment: Please share the result of your powershell script. Thanks.

Comment: @KGahbiche I have written the output. Don't have permission to take screenshot from server.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `SPList.GetItems(SPView)` method to get items from the view. Example:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://aissp2013
$list = $web.Lists["YourList"]
$view = $list.Views["ViewName"]
$items = $list.GetItems($view)
foreach($item in $items)
{
 #Play with item
}
```

**UPDATE**

Scrrenshot:
[image]

Comment: I have tried that @Nadeem Yousuf but it returns all the items in original list not that particular view. I edited the 'All Documents' view and tried this it didn't work.

Comment: @Asu, not sure why this isn't working for you. see the results of my test run in attached screenshot.

Comment: I added a filter saying 'Name = A' but after running script all the folders(A,B,C) were shown. I even tried the option "Show all items without folders" but in script output I got all folders. I can see the change in SP site but not in script output.. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Tested that as well and working properly. Perhaps try editing the question. Add some screenshots and the script so that we can check what the issue is.

Comment: I have edited the question..

Comment: @Asu, it is strange.

Comment: I have no idea also. If you get any clue let me know