# PowerShell Script to retrieve every and only List / Library items in a specific view in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, splistitem, spview

I am trying to iterate over each item in specific view for a list in SharePoint 2010.

What i have so far works to return items in the view, but only the items in the first paginated view for that set.  So even though all Documents contains 11K items i only get 30 returned to me.

I found this question and it was answered, but the code there doesnt work for me:
 [Powershell Script to get items only in a particular view of SharePoint List/library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134830)

Here is what i am trying:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myweb
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
$view = $list.Views["MyViewName"]
$items = $list.GetItems($view)
$cntItems = 0
foreach($item in $items)
{
   $cntItems++
}
write-host $cntItems
```

The above returns `30` since that is what the view has as its page item limit.

```
30
```

Is there some setting or some other way to do what i am trying to do?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPQuery in Powershell

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
       Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myweb/
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.Query = $list.Views["ViewName"].Query
$items = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
$cntItems = 0
foreach($item in $items)
{
   $cntItems++
}
write-host $cntItems
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked.  It was a little slow so i ended up adding a `$spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $items.ListItemCollectionPosition` line and a `do while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://simosi.com");
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        SPList lst = web.Lists.TryGetList("Tasks");
        if (lst != null)
        {


            SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
            q.Query = lst.Views["ActiveTask"].Query;

            SPListItemCollection items =lst.GetItems(q);
            Console.WriteLine(items.Count);

        }
```

[Sorurce](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/093bdd1d-a92b-49d4-9761-77a700be7e42/getitemview-return-all-items-regardless-of-rowlimit-which-is-set?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious), you can also try to disable the paging as mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code : I think it should be better in performance wise

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://portal.sharepoint.com
$list = $web.Lists["LargeList"]
$view = $list["your view name"]

$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery($view)

do
 {
      $listItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
      $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
      foreach($item in $listItems)
        {
         Write-Host $item.Title
        }
 }
while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

How it will help.